# Is there a way to spin up an in-memmory redis in my spring app

Tags: spring, maven, redis

I have a spring app that uses redis for caching. I want to be able to spin up an in-memory redis while my integration tests are running. Is it possible to configure a redis in maven that would only be used for my CI when my app is building running tests?

Comment: I have never used maven, but in case of running tests for my python app I just run an instance of Redis on the custom port with specified config. Redis can be configured as non-persistent storage and you will not have problems with data clean-up after test.

Comment: @AliakseiRamanau but how would you start up a specific redis instance with a host and port if one doesn't exist? I just want to spin-up an embedded redis to run my tests and then tear if down afterwards

Comment: >>> but how would you start up a specific redis instance with a host and port if one doesn't exist? 

I don't know anything about embedding Redis into Java applications. It's a piece of software written in C. However, it can be runned on localhost with binding to default port, where you run your tests.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to start up a test container with redis. Docs can be found here: https://www.testcontainers.org/